# Tab bar icons pixelated and cut off

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to set my `UITabbar` icons via interface builder.  Here is what I am seeing:

[image]

Two problems here:

1. Why is the bottom cut off?  The dimensions of these 3 images in order is
   64x42, 44x44, 46x46.
2. Why are they pixelated/blurry?

I am following the guidelines for tab bar icons listed here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

I am not using the image, image@2x naming scheme.  I am just setting these in IB.  This app will be only released to devices with retina displays in any case.  The screenshot is from an iPhone 5.

Comment: `I am not using the image, image@2x naming scheme` therein lies your problem likely. You need to use it so iPhone 4 and 5 know that its retina display.

Comment: Ahh..thanks that fixed it.  I didn't realize i *had* to name my images @2x for them to work properly.  Does this rule not apply to `UIImageView`?  If you reply an answer, I will check it for you.

Comment: In interface builder use image.png instead of image@2x.png

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only indication UIKit uses to determine if an image is retina is if it has the @2x scheme. Otherwise, UIKit will treat it as a non-retina image. This is why it is showing the image double the size it should be, because you have not used the naming scheme to tell UIKit that the image should be rendered 4 pixels per screen point.